# Run Tomcat7 as tomcat7 (or any other) user

Tags: tomcat7

What will be the recommended way to ensure that a Tomcat7 instance is running as the tomcat7 (or any other) user?

I suppose that I can modify `tomcat7-instance/bin/startup.sh` and `tomcat7-instance/bin/shutdown.sh` and add 'su tomcat7' at the top.

In Tomcat6 I think it was the environment variable `TOMCAT6_USER`.

Comment: If you are asking for the "secure way" most likely will provoke debates. Now if you ask "how to set a different user for tomcat7?" that is answerable. BTW, tomcat starts with user tomcat, as far I remember if you installed the deb package..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most common way is to install the standard `tomcat7` package with `apt-get` and to start it using:

```
sudo service tomcat7 start
```

The default user and group are configured in `/etc/default/tomcat7` as you can see in this excerpt:

```
# Run Tomcat as this user ID. Not setting this or leaving it blank will use the
# default of tomcat7.
TOMCAT7_USER=tomcat7

# Run Tomcat as this group ID. Not setting this or leaving it blank will use
# the default of tomcat7.
TOMCAT7_GROUP=tomcat7
```

Comment: TOMCAT7_USER and TOMCAT7_GROUP was what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: I modified TOMCAT7_USER in tomcat7-instance/bin/setenv.sh and started the server. But if I display the process using ps the user is not the one specified in TOMCAT7_USER.

Comment: Why don't you modify it directly in `/etc/default/tomcat7`?

Comment: Let's say that I have two Tomcat user instances and I want to launch them as different users.

Comment: That's a scenario I'm not familiar with, but in this case I don't think you can run Tomcat as a service and the above config does not apply. Maybe you should ask a separate question about that.

Answer (score 11):

*EDIT: Please read comments below! This solution may not be applicable to all situations.*

The accepted answer is great but since I run Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu 14.04 there were some additional things I needed to do in order to get everything running:

1. You need to stop the tomcat service before editing the file `/etc/default/tomcat7`. Once you change the user and group, it will no longer be possible to stop a service using the old user.
2. Change the user and group in the file `/etc/default/tomcat7`
3. You need to change ownership of the folder `/var/log/tomcat7` and all of it's files. Please note that it is an advantage to keep the adm group so that all adm users can read the logs.

   `sudo chown -R newuser:adm /var/log/tomcat7`
4. Change ownership of the folder `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`

   `sudo chown -R newuser:newgroup /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`
5. If running on port 80/443 on Ubuntu 14.04 you need to change ownership of the authbind files:

   `sudo chown newuser /etc/authbind/byport/80`

   `sudo chown newuser /etc/authbind/byport/443`
6. Change ownership of the working folder

   `sudo chown newuser:adm /var/cache/tomcat7`

   `sudo chown -R newuser:newgroup /var/cache/tomcat7/Catalina`
7. Make config files readable. Here you have two options: Either add you new user to the tomcat7 group by:

   `sudo usermod -a -G tomcat7 newuser`

   ...or change ownership of the config files:

   `sudo chown -R :newgroup /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/*`
8. If you have other files that your web-apps are accessing such as log files configuration files etc. then you need to change ownership of those files as well.
9. Now, everything should be ready to fire up the service again with the new user.

EDIT 2: After upgrading to tomcat 8 and Ubuntu 18.04 another issue appeared when running tomcat as a different user. In the script `/etc/init.d/tomcat8` the following line seems to alter the home folder of the tomcat user but the result is not what you want if you are using a different user.

```
usermod --home /var/lib/tomcat8 $TOMCAT8_USER > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
```

By removing or commenting this line out, you can avoid to have the home folder altered for the new tomcat user.

Comment: There si a huge problem with your answer. Upon the next tomcat7 package upgrade (security fix/bugfix), your setup will break because apt will install the new tomcat7 package version using the same user (tomcat7) again. So you can't do unattended upgrades and have to remember to chown after each upgrade.

Comment: I did not realize that and I don't have any good solution for it either at the moment. Any suggestions, anyone?

Comment: There is no such file in Tomcat9.

Comment: Re step 3: you'd also want to edit `/etc/logrotate.d/tomcat7` `create` directive replacing `tomcat7` with your new user.