# Permission issues with tomcat

Tags: server, permissions, tomcat, tomcat7

I installed Tomcat 7 following the [Ubuntu guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/tomcat.html). The server is working and gives me the "It works!" page on `http://localhost:8080/`.

Now I want to setup my own webapp using Netbeans. I generated a new *Web Project* with Java EE 6 and Tomcat 7. The user is on the `/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/tomcat-users.xml` file properly configured.

When I run the project everything seems ok, but when I open the browser it displays [a 500 error](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8169145/).

- The [Tomcat output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8153678/) mentions permission errors trying to access `tomcat7/logs` and
- The [IDE logs](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8169113/) trying to access `tomcat7/conf`.

Files permissions:

```
lucio@lucio-pc:/$ ll /var/lib/tomcat7/logs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 jul 24 18:07 /var/lib/tomcat7/logs -> ../../log/tomcat7/
lucio@lucio-pc:/$ ll /var/log/tomcat7/
total 136
drwxr-x---  2 tomcat7 adm      4096 ago 28 10:50 ./
drwxrwxr-x 15 root    syslog   4096 ago 28 09:29 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat7 tomcat7   800 ago 26 17:23 catalina.2014-08-26.log.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat7 tomcat7  5173 ago 27 21:59 catalina.2014-08-27.log
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat7 tomcat7 31285 ago 28 10:36 catalina.2014-08-28.log
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat7 root    44192 ago 28 10:36 catalina.out
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat7 tomcat7    45 ago 26 16:19 localhost.2014-08-26.log.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat7 tomcat7     0 ago 27 11:15 localhost.2014-08-27.log
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat7 tomcat7   433 ago 28 09:49 localhost.2014-08-28.log
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat7 tomcat7  7435 ago 26 17:23 localhost_access_log.2014-08-26.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat7 tomcat7     0 ago 27 11:15 localhost_access_log.2014-08-27.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat7 tomcat7 15186 ago 28 09:58 localhost_access_log.2014-08-28.txt
```

I don't understand why can't access the files, you can see that the user and group `tomcat7` has permissions to the files. Is there a user for the JVM that needs privileges over the files?

I also tried changing files ownerships as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18869318/1505348) but it doesn't change at all.

---

The [`/etc/default/tomcat7`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8168521/) file has:

```
TOMCAT7_USER=tomcat7
TOMCAT7_GROUP=tomcat7
```

So I guess it is running as `tomcat7` user.

---

I added my user into the `tomcat7` group:

```
sudo usermod -aG tomcat7 $USER
```

And then restarted the machine, but the problem persist.

Comment: Is tomcat running as the tomcat7 user?

Comment: It's been too long since I used tomcat, but 2 things occur to me: Don't *you* need to be in the tomcat7 group to allow the program to access the log?  And also, it seems like it really wants to access a temp file in `/var/lib/tomcat7/temp`; does that exist?  It may be the same permission problem.  Maybe you just need to add yourself to the tomcat7 group.

Comment: Also, you would need to make the files group writable to use my idea.  And there is more information [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/371848/39753) that might help.

Comment: It seems the user (human or application) that run tomcat7 don't have the permission to access /var/lib/tomcat7/ and especially the logs folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I noticed two problems here.

Two lines in the error log stood out to me:

```
SEVERE: Cannot find specified temporary folder at /var/lib/tomcat7/temp
```

and:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/tomcat-users.xml (Permission denied)
```

[Doing a bit of diagnosis with Lucio](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17429331#17429331), I figured out that the `tomcat-users.xml` file was not owned by Tomcat, but instead `root`. Change the permissions to the proper ones by running the command:

```
sudo chown tomcat7:tomcat7 /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/tomcat-users.xml
```

Also, create the folder `/var/lib/tomcat7/temp` with tomcat permissions, like so:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/tomcat7/temp && sudo chown -R tomcat7:tomcat7 /var/lib/tomcat7/temp
```

Finally, fixing the logs should be done by making `/var/lib/tomcat7/logs` owned by the `tomcat7` user/group. The `/var/log/tomcat7/` should also be owned by the `tomcat7` user AND group.

Comment: For me, changing the permissions on the `tomcat-user.xml` file was enough. Doing the same for the logs didn't worked but the application is running anyway :-)